# Touchpad doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: touchpad, 13.10

I upgraded Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 on my laptop.

Now my touchpad doesn't work anymore. But a external mouse works perfectly. I've tried to fix the problem with "system settings", "mouse & touchpad". But this didn't help.

What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>. Type the following:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This will remove the psmouse driver and add it back again.